# How to programatically add block to Drupal 7 page tpl AND respect visibility rules?

Tags: blocks

I want to add a block programatically to a page.tpl.php file in my Drupal 7 theme BUT I want it to respect the block's visibility rules.

I'm open to defining new visibility rules in PHP too but it seems whenever I manually invoke a module via code without assigning the block in a region it does not adhere to the block's visibility rules.

Comment: out of curiousity, what's the purpose of by-passing Drupals block system and manually including it in the theme?

Comment: We're creating blocks manually in a custom module and displaying the blocks via the theme.

Comment: for future reference, that would have been useful information in the question, as well as the current code you were employing. Glad you got it working though

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was in how I was rendering the blocks.

Using this code to render my block added the block to Drupal's "knowledge" of the block being on the page.

```
$block = block_load($module, $bid);
$blockStuff = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
$output = drupal_render($blockStuff);
print $output;
```